# What is the AD flag in a DNS query?

Tags: networking, dns, udp

I am chasing down some weird DNS behaviour in our network, and I would appreciate your help:

We have an old router that also acts as a local DNS server (DrayTek 2830n) at 192.168.1.1. The symptom is that a Windows 10 machine can successfully query that server whereas an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not get any response (although that machine can query 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 without any problems).

When I wireshark'ed the traffic, the first difference I noticed was the "AD flag". The query from the Windows machine (either through the browser or by `nslookup` from the command line) looks like this,

```
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 58922, Dst Port: 53
Domain Name System (query)
Transaction ID: 0x0002
Flags: 0x0100 Standard query
    0... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a query
    .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
    .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
    .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
    .... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
    .... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
Questions: 1
Answer RRs: 0
Authority RRs: 0
Additional RRs: 0
```

while the corresponding query from the Ubuntu machine is

```
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 35155, Dst Port: 53
Domain Name System (query)
Transaction ID: 0x85ee
Flags: 0x0120 Standard query
    0... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a query
    .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
    .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
    .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
    .... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
    .... .... ..1. .... = AD bit: Set
    .... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
Questions: 1
Answer RRs: 0
Authority RRs: 0
Additional RRs: 1
```

Indeed, the AD flag is the culprit. When I explicitly unset it in the query from the Ubuntu machine, say, `dig +noadflag @192.168.1.1 www.somewhere.edu` then the router does respond to the query. Public servers such as 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8, however, always respond.

Now my questions are these

- what is the purpose of the AD bit in the DNS query?
- why does Windows 10 unset it whereas Linux usually sets it?
- why might our router respond only when the flag is unset whereas every other DNS server that I tried, responds irrespectively of that flag?

Thank your in advance for your help.

HPF

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. §4.1.1 of RFC 1035, and then refinements in §6.1 of RFC 2535 explain the DNS header and the `AD` bit but only in replies. Then RFC6840 §5.7 finally defines `AD` in query: "setting the AD bit in a query as a signal
   indicating that the requester understands and is interested in the
   value of the AD bit in the response. "